# Detecting rotation from a fixed sensor

Tags: sensor, magnetics, rotary, magnetometer

I am looking for a way how to detect the rotation of an object that is hanging from the ceiling, attached with a rope. Since the object can freely rotate for many revolutions (until the rope is too twisted), there is no way to provide power to any sensors and/or microcontrollers if they are attached to the hanging object. Batteries are not an option since they would have to be replaced regularly. So I thought maybe I could pass the rope through a pipe, attach a magnet to the rope, and sense the position of the magnet by a magnetic sensor that is fixed on the pipe (see the diagram).

For context: this is an installation in an art exhibition. The object is freely hanging in the rope and is expected to be manually spun by the visitors. When it spins, sound effects are played on several speakers that are placed around the object. The object is firmly attached to the rope and thus pulls the rope along with it. The rotation would go several revolutions in one direction, and when the rope has aggregated enough resistance, the rotation would get slower until it starts going in the other direction.

The plate with magnets would be attached as close as possible to the object so that it could be assumed that the rotation of the plate reflects the actual rotation of the object.

[image]

Since the pipe is fixed, there is no problem powering the sensor and microcontroller to read it.

I found [this magnetometer - HMC5883L](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/301) and would like to know if that could be used to read the position of the magnet. Or maybe there is much better way to achieve what I'm looking for, with of without magnets.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid doing something when the rope is spinning and hence you need to know if the rope is spinning? Does the rope have to spin? More context.

Comment: Hall switch is simpler than magnetometer. You could also use photo detectors with a slotted or marked disk if you want no magnets

Comment: @Andyaka edited the post to provide more context

Comment: Why a rope? Why not a shaft with a bearing?

Comment: Why do you need to check if it's spinning? This may sound like a pointless question to you but, may lead to a better solution.

Comment: @DaveTweed because they want the rope to act like a radial amortizer: when the the object is spinned in one direction and left to run by itself, then it would keep going, slow down and then go the other direction.

Comment: @Andyaka added to the post - because the rotation information is then used to play sound effects around the object.

Comment: Also, diametrically polarized tube magnets exist. A little difficult to find though. No metal plate needed if your cable is thin enough.

Comment: You may need to consider that visitors may push the object sideways. An optical sensor is another option. You will need to decide how slow the motion should be to be considered stopped.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 2 magnetic sensors, spaced 90 degree apart, and one or perhaps multiple magnets around the rope, then you can use quadrature encoding/decoding to detect the amount and direction of rotation.

Painting the rope with vertical stripes and using a pair of optical sensors (maybe IR with IR LEDs) around the rope would be another option